# $.parseXML cannot parse XML with script tag inside

Tags: jquery, xml, jbpm, bpmn

I'm trying to parse the following BPMN 2 XML with `$.parseXML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions id="Definition"
         xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools">
    <process processType="Private"
         isExecutable="true"
         id="com.sample.bpmn"
         name="Sample Process"
         tns:packageName="defaultPackage" >
        <scriptTask id="_2" name="Sample Script" scriptFormat="http://www.java.com/java">
            <script>person.id</script>
        </scriptTask>
    </process>
</definitions>
```

but it returns with the following:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions id="Definition"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools">
    <process processType="Private"
             isExecutable="true"
             id="com.sample....<omitted>...id
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7Va/6/)

---

**EDIT**

Later in the code I have to find specific parts of the XML like process, definitions etc.:

```
xmlDoc   = $.parseXML(data),
$xml     = $(xmlDoc),
$def     = $xml.find('definitions'),
$process = $def.find('process'),
```

Comment: what did you want to do ?


$.parseXML use DOMParser() which  parse XML from strings into DOM trees. But you already have DOM

What is нщгк goal ?

Comment: later I have to find specific sub-trees of the XML , for example: $xml.find('process'). Question edited.

Comment: why not to use jQuery selectors to get data?

Comment: I do use jQuery selectors to get the data from $xml, I'm not sure what you mean, could you please edit the fiddle?

Comment: To make things clearer, my problem is that `$.parseXML` _can not parse the above XML_. I know there are alternatives for the above code, but parserXML supposed to parse that XML, but it won't. Any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

```
 var scriptBody = $('script#scriptBody').text();
 console.log(scriptBody);

 var parser = new DOMParser(); var xml =
 parser.parseFromString(scriptBody, 'text/xml'); console.log(xml);
```

work fine. Strange, course jquery use this implementation ( not for IE )

on debug $ function

```
parseXML: function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
},
```

problems in xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" )

> "This page contains the following errors:error on line 2 at column 6:
>   XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Below is a
>   rendering of the page up to the first error."

if i remove xml declaration i get

> "This page contains the following errors:error on line 10 at column
>   29: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: I tested this in Chrome 33.0.1750.149 and in FF 27.0.1 and isn't working. In which browser you tested this?

Comment: In your case, is the XML printed in console.log(xml) identical to the one that was parsed? In my case it isn't.

Comment: error on close tag </script> can you use something different ?

Comment: What do you mean by use something different, this is a valid XML defined by the BPMN 2 spec. `$.parseXML` supposed to parse it. Please read again the original question.

Comment: i read. Problem is here var scriptBody = $('script#scriptBody').html(); or var container = document.getElemenetByid('scriptBody'); - Print content to console and you'll see, than string is not equal to tag content