# jQuery parseHTML and parseXML behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401311/parsexml-cannot-parse-xml-with-script-tag-inside) I was looking for the reason why `$.parseXML` throws exception when it encounters a `script` tag inside a BPMN file. I though this is an issue with jQuery and also posted this on their issue tracker and got a suggestion to try `$.parseHTML`.

The difference is that `$.parseHTML` doesn't throw any exception but it silently ignores the tags after the first `script` tag. Here is the valid XML I used for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<someroot>
    <firsttag>
           <peacefultag></peacefultag>
    </firsttag>
    <secondtag>
        <a>asdsa</a>
    </secondtag>
</someroot>
```

and the following simple selectors:

```
$(result1).find('firsttag').length; // 1
$(result1).find('secondtag').length; // 1
```

If you replace the `peacefultag` in the above XML with `script` this happens:

```
$(result1).find('secondtag').length; // becomes 0.
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7m6w/

Am I missing something, is this the expected behavior?

Comment: This is what I would expect with parse HTML, yeah. How does your test XML work with `parseXML`

Comment: @GerbenJacobs it fails with an error.

Comment: I see. The problem is (which SajithNair points out) that in your jsfiddle, you're using `<script>` to house the XML. When I put it in a variable, it works.

Comment: The takeaway here is that one thing you can't get away with when using `<script>` tags as a place to stash random content is to include `</script>` as part of the content.

Comment: These BPMN 2 XMLs may contain several `<script>` tags. I'm not allowed to modify their content. But first of all, I expected `.text()` will grab everything inside the given element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print `scriptBody2` to console. You can see that the closing `</script>` tag of the inner script tag is is used to math with the first script tag. Thus everything which follows the inner  tag, is ignored.

This is not a problem with parseHTML, because parseHTML is getting only the partial tags to parse.

http://jsfiddle.net/3gxEM/

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer because it looks like this has nothing to do with parseXML or parseHTML, `.text()` is the functions which returns the unexpected content.